# Windows Powershell directory specific functions

Tags: powershell

How I can create functions inside my `$profile` file that will be executed only if I am inside some specific path when  trying to execute them?

Comment: Do you mean you want functions to execute when you change to that directory or you only want functions to have side effects only if you're currently in a certain directory?

Comment: @Michael Kelley, Second one. I can put `if(){}` inside this functions but they will be still autocomplited on *tab* key pressed (but I do not want this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into PowerShell to effectively hide a command based on any sort of context (e.g. your current directory.)

In PowerShell V3 or greater, there are some event handlers around command lookup that you could use.  One solution would look something like this:

```
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.PreCommandLookupAction = {
    param([string]$commandName,
          [System.Management.Automation.CommandLookupEventArgs]$eventArgs)

    if ($commandName -eq 'MyCommand' -and $pwd -eq 'some directory')
    {
        $eventArgs.StopSearch = $true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your profile is evaluated at PowerShell start up so current directory doesn't really come into play.  Any function inside the profile will be available as soon as your able to use the PowerShell console.  You could re-implement the tabexpansion2 function to not tab-complete certain functions based on the current directory but that seems a bit over-the-top.  Another option would be to override the prompt function and depending on the current directory, set the function's visibility to either public or private.  If they are private, they won't show up in tab expansion e.g.:

```
$func = Get-Command MyFunc
$func.Visibility = 'private' # or 'public'
```